# Group by causing using temporary; using filesort

Tags: mysql

I got an old project to maintain recently (I'm not an experienced developer), and I found an SQL like this:

```
SELECT
    g.goods_id, o.order_status,
    SUM(IF(o.shipping_status=0, g.quantity, 0)) AS 'pending',
    SUM(IF(o.shipping_status=3, g.quantity, 0)) AS 'picking',
    SUM(IF(o.shipping_status=5, g.quantity, 0)) AS 'shipping'
FROM
    order_info AS o
LEFT JOIN
    order_goods AS g ON g.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE o.order_status in (1,5,6)
GROUP BY g.goods_id
```

I removed some annoying stuff so it looks much cleaner.
but still, it took me about 10 seconds to get the result.
The database has only 60 thousand rows of records. and it has all the indexes that it needs. 
And the explain command shows that the SQL is '**Using temporary; Using filesort**'. I think the 'group by' clause caused the problem. 
So, I wonder if I can optimize or rewrite it in another way. which will give me the same functionality and both avoid the extra sorting stuff. 
Any help would be appreciate and sorry for my bad English.

Indexes for order_goods:
**order_id, goods_id...**
Indexes for order_info:
**order_id, order_status, shipping_status...**

The explain output are here:

[image]

Comment: You do not necesssarily have to rewrite the query, but rather create proper indexes. Pls provide the exact explain output and the details of the existing indexes of the 2 affected tables. However, pls note that the conditional sums will always be slow. This is the reason why pivot tables are often prepared at the client side, not at the server side.

Comment: Post the explain please

Comment: Thanks for response. I have post the explain output. But, I don't think that would help much.

Comment: You seem to be missing order_status from the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Nope, I don't need to group the order_status. Is there another way to accomplish? I mean, rewrite the SQL.

Comment: @Xericoder technically, you have to group by on order status as well. In mysql under certain configuration settings you can get away not doing so, but this is against the sql standard.

Comment: Why do you outer-join the `order_goods` table? Do you expect to find `order_info` records without any related `order_goods` records? Think about what that will do to your results: You'll get a row with `g.goods_id` = null and arbitrarily chosen `order_status` and sums.

Comment: "Nope, I don't need to group the order_status." Erm, yes you do.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm really sorry, that I just found out this SQL isn't the one that costs me 10 seconds. It's the previous paging query. I really sorry for wasting all your time.  I'm just got the job. and started my career. The codes are really sucks. almost made my quit this job. :'(

Comment: /clap
no worries we all fail , next time look better and that's all ;)

Comment: With an inner join, which I suppose is all you need, your query would be standard compliant by the way, as `o.order_status` is functionally dependent on `g.goods_id` (for there is only only one `order_info` record per `order_goods` record). With the outer join it is not, because `g.goods_id` = null would relate to all `order_info` without `order_goods` records.

Comment: I thought an inner join would cause Cartesian product and cost me more time. Maybe I'm wrong. Anyway, if g.goods_id = null, then the quantity would be null too. I guess. which... yeah , It will generates a row contains all null columns. Thank you very much. That is helpful.

Comment: You get a cartesian product with the lack of criteria. So `CROSS JOIN` always produces cartesian products - it is made for this pupose - and inner and outer joins produce them when you're missing criteria, e.g. `on t1.a = t2.a` instead of `on t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b`.

Comment: OK, I get that. I'm just don't know much about how mysql deals with those kind of situations. Frankly, I don't know much about how database works either. I will work on it. Really thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest to change

```
WHERE o.order_status in (1,5,6)
```

for

```
WHERE (o.order_status = 1 OR o.order_status = 5 OR o.order_status = 6)
```

Should't change to much... but i know that in is quite slow in some mysql version , depends also of the records you have in both tables.

You also could change the if from the select sentence and instead of doing a if in each row you could use it in a where getting just the rows with the status 0,3,5 and adding a group by shipping status.

```
AND (o.shipping_status = 0 OR o.order_status = 3 OR o.order_status = 5)
```

All sentence in  a row

```
SELECT
g.goods_id, o.order_status,
SUM(g.quantity) AS 'quantity'
FROM
order_info AS o
LEFT JOIN
order_goods AS g ON g.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE (o.order_status = 1 OR o.order_status = 5 OR o.order_status = 6) AND 
(o.shipping_status = 0 OR o.shipping_status = 3 OR o.shipping_status = 5)
GROUP BY g.goods_id,o.shipping_status
```

Take care you will not get te same result as expected, but i think this is the fastes way to get your result and maybe it's not so hard to change a bit of your code.

Try execute this and let's see how times goes ;)

Comment: I knew that one. but thank you anyway. It's not my codes. I just got this job a couple days ago.